# hibernate.properties vs hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate, configuration

What is the order of precedence between hibernate.properties and hibernate.cfg.xml ?

For what I know hibernate.cfg.xml (if exists in the app's classpath) overrides hibernate.properties. Is my assumption correct ?

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-xmlconfig):

> An alternative approach to configuration is to specify a full configuration in a file named hibernate.cfg.xml. This file can be used as a replacement for the hibernate.properties file or, **if both are present, to override properties.**

Comment: A link for the documentation would be appreciated.